# Yammer Posts using javascript

Tags: office365, yammer

I have site in Office 365 site. I had integrate Yammer in my site using javascript by custom web part.

but I am not able to get all posts like default App of Yammer(on Office 365). I am getting error for API call for sometimes.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: any mechanism which default yammer App using? either javascript or code behind?

Comment: What API calls are you tryong? What API are you using? What error message are you getting? When do you get it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that. But nobody can help you without giving more detail like what did you try and what kind of error you are seeing.

Checkout the Yammer Javascript SDK if you haven't done so yet: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/js-sdk